# Duende.IdentityServer crashes navigating to Register/Login Blazor WASM

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, duende-identity-server

I have a Blazor WASM (PWA) that's .NET 7. I was scaffolding the identity pages and customizing them (register, login, etc.), when suddenly, navigating to register or login crashes the entire app locally. I reverted back to the last working commit version I had and when navigating, the browser closes automatically on navigation so I don't have any browser exception in the console to view. All I have to go on is this in the output tab of Visual Studio. I can clearly see it's an issue with `Duende.IdentityServer`, but I didn't specifically change any configuration from one moment to the next and not sure how to fix.

Any help?

```
Duende.IdentityServer.Events.DefaultEventService: Information: {
      "ClientId": "xxx.Client",
      "ClientName": "xxx.Client",
      "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7147/authentication/login-callback",
      "Endpoint": "Authorize",
      "Scopes": "xxx.ServerAPI openid profile",
      "GrantType": "authorization_code",
      "Error": "login_required",
      "Category": "Token",
      "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
      "EventType": "Failure",
      "Id": 2001,
      "ActivityId": "0HMPG9LBONBM1:0000003B",
      "TimeStamp": "2023-03-29T12:01:57Z",
      "ProcessId": 45912,
      "LocalIpAddress": "::1:7147",
      "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
    }
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
          Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
          DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
          Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
          DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

Comment: did you happen to solve it?